# Making button go full-width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html, responsive-design

I want a button to take up the full width of the column, but having difficulties...

```
<div class="span9 btn-block">
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" type="button">Block level button</button>
</div>
```

**How do I make the button as wide as the column?**

Answer (score 893):

### Bootstrap v3 & v4

Use `btn-block` class on your button/element

### Bootstrap v2

Use `input-block-level` class on your button/element

Comment: For button groups you'll need to add `btn-block` to the `btn-group` wrapper as well.

Comment: For bootstrap 5.1+, `btn-block` class doesn't exist anymore and won't work, check updated answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061139/making-button-go-full-width/68974259#68974259

Comment: For Bootstrap 5.2+,  we should use d-grid class. For example: <div class="d-grid"><button>Hello!</button></div>

Answer (score 52):

In case some are noticing `btn-block` not working anymore in bootstrap 5.1+:

It was dropped in bootstrap 5.1 ([changelog](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/#buttons)):

> Breaking Dropped .btn-block for utilities. Instead of using .btn-block
> on the .btn, wrap your buttons with .d-grid and a .gap-* utility to
> space them as needed. Switch to responsive classes for even more
> control over them. Read the docs for some examples.

You can now make a button full width by adding the class `w-100`, as the authors do in their official Pricing example page:

```
<button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary">
    Sign up for free
</button>
```

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/pricing/

If you want to make a stack of block buttons, the official docs recommend the following :

```
<div class="d-grid gap-2">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/buttons/#block-buttons

Comment: So how do you catch something like this? I spent over an hour trying to figure out why btn-block was no longer working! Do you track the change logs??? Thank you for the solution.

Comment: @stromyc same here, I was scratching my head for a while, and found out they had changed it. I guess it's always living and breathing, so have to keep an eye for those.

Answer (score 43):

**Why not use the Bootstrap predefined class `input-block-level` that does the job?**

```
<a href="#" class="btn input-block-level">Full-Width Button</a> <!-- BS2 -->
<a href="#" class="btn form-control">Full-Width Button</a> <!-- BS3 -->

<!-- And let's join both for BS# :) -->
<a href="#" class="btn input-block-level form-control">Full-Width Button</a>
```

*Learn more here in the [Control Sizing^](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html) section.*

Comment: @fguillen **Not using BS anymore but try `form-control` class.** It appears to make things 100% wide in the samples.

Comment: As of bs4, @Layke 's answer seems more up to date and covers bs 2, 3 and 4.  Neither option above did anything useful for me on bs4.  Apologize for being chatty with this, but the accepted answer doesn't seem a good idea and this one appears deprecated.

Answer (score 38):

**Bootstrap / CSS**

Use `col-12`, `btn-block`, `w-100`, `form-control` or `width:100%`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

         <button class="btn btn-success col-12">
             class="col-12"
         </button>
    
         <button class="btn btn-primary w-100">
             class="w-100"
         </button>

         <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
             class="btn-block"
         </button>
         
         <button class="btn btn-success form-control">
             class="form-control"
         </button>
         
         <button class="btn btn-danger" style="width:100%">
             style="width:100%"
         </button>
```

Answer (score 30):

I simply used this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the way to do it with btn-lg.  form-control does not work.

Answer (score 12):

use

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
  ...
</div>
```

but it only works for <a> elements and not <button> elements.

see: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-justified

Comment: The question was about buttons not `btn-group`s, there is a more accepted response referring to `btn-block` class by Layke.

Answer (score 10):

You should add these styles to a CSS sheet

```
div .no-padding {
  padding:0;
}

button .full-width{
  width:100%;
  //display:block; //only if you're having issues
}
```

Then change add the classes to your code

```
<div class="span9 btn-block no-padding">
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary full-width" type="button">Block level button</button>
</div>
```

I haven't tested this and I'm not 100% sure what you want, but I think this will get you close.

Comment: I corrected a typo in my code, should have been div instead of span in the top css entry. Can you confirm the styles are being applied? Does the button's width change at all?

Comment: `btn-block` is the attribute that saved me! Was pulling my hair out.. Now I go back and search http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons, that attribute was documented there - doh ;)

Answer (score 10):

In Bootstrap 5, the class `btn-block` doesn't work anymore. But instead, you can add the class `w-100` to the button to make it as wide as its container.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row"><div class=" col-5 ">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100  " href="# "><span>Button 1</span></a> 
</div><div class="col-5 ">

            <a class=" btn btn-primary w-100 weiss " href="# "><span>Button 2</span></a> 
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I would have thought this would be the most bootstrap-esque way of doing things:

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-success col-xs-12'> First buttton baby </button>
```

All I'm doing is adding the class `col-xs-12` to the button.

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="button">Block level button</button>
</div>
```

In Bootstrap 3, this should be all you need. I believe `btn-large` was overriding the width of `btn-block`.

Answer (score 2):

Update 2022:

You have multiple ways to make button full width.

1. You can add the `w-100` to the class.
2. You can add `d-grid` and `gap-2`to a container above the button:

```html
<div class="d-grid gap-2"> <!-- Here -->
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

         <button class="btn btn-success col-12">
             class="col-12"
         </button>
    
         <button class="btn btn-primary w-100">
             class="w-100"
         </button>

         <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
             class="btn-block"
         </button>
         
         <button class="btn btn-success form-control">
             class="form-control"
         </button>
         
         <button class="btn btn-danger" style="width:100%">
             style="width:100%"
         </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. We can Use a Block Level Full-Width Button
2. Create block level buttons—those that span the full width of a parent—by adding .btn-block.

   ```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
      Block level button
   </button>

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">
      Block level button
   </button>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the css property `width: 100%`:

```html
<button style="width: 100%;">Test Button</button>
```