# Bootstrap 4: Dropdown main button (input-group + btn-group) with 100% width (or auto)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, flexbox, width

I have an issue with the width of a button present in an *input group*. I'm using Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6 (Flexbox).

This is what I have.

[image: before]

This is what I want.

[image: after]

This is the code.

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-sort fa-fw"></i></span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown">Name</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item active" href="#">Name</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Author</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">NewDark version</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Related game</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">First release date</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Last update date</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary active"><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc fa-fw"></i></button></span>
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-desc fa-fw"></i></button></span>
</div>
```

Does someone have any idea how I can automatically fix the width of this button? Maybe with one specific Flexbox property?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown">Name</button>
```

---

**Bootply code:** http://www.bootply.com/DRLKMrc99S

Comment: It's good idea to give it in working (with cdn jquery etc.) code snippet.

Comment: @Sylogista http://www.bootply.com/DRLKMrc99S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added `btn-block` and `text-left` classes. See more at [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061139/making-button-go-full-width).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i></span>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Just type something..." type="text">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-clear wdh-4-rem">
          <div class="loaded">100</div>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-sort fa-fw"></i></span>
        <span class="input-group-btn btn-block">
          <div class="btn-group btn-block">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown">Name</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
              <a class="dropdown-item active" href="#">Name</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Author</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">NewDark version</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Related game</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">First release date</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Last update date</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </span>
        <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary active"><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc fa-fw"></i></button></span>
        <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-desc fa-fw"></i></button></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/PFOMxDHJoL